# Возврат нескольких значений одновременно из функции в Python

Tags: python, pandas, return

помогите пожалуйста с моим небольшим вопросом. У меня не получается вывести из функции Python два значения. Либо могу вывести поочередно одно из двух, либо получается вывести просто в виде какого то кода. В результате хотелось бы получить чтобы выводилась таблица и под ней следом график. Я в принципе прописал уже return в конце кода, но не знаю как заставить их работать одновременно. Заранее благодарю.

```
def calculate_rolling_ret(installs, logins):
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


installs = installs.drop_duplicates().dropna()

logins = logins.drop_duplicates().dropna()
logins = logins[(logins['is_tester'] ==0) & (logins['is_youtuber'] ==0)][['client_id','event_timestamp']]

work_table = logins.merge(
    installs,
    on='client_id',
    how='inner')
work_table

work_table['event_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(work_table['event_timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
work_table['install_date'] = pd.to_datetime(work_table['install_date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

work_table['week_start'] = work_table['install_date'].dt.to_period('W').dt.start_time
work_table['lifetime'] = work_table['event_timestamp'] - work_table['install_date']
work_table['lifetime'] = work_table['lifetime'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
work_table['lifetime'] = work_table['lifetime'].astype('int')

work_table['event_timestamp'] = work_table['event_timestamp'].dt.date
work_table

min_lifetime = work_table['lifetime'].min()

max_lifetime = work_table['lifetime'].max()


count_id={}

for lifetime in range(0, max_lifetime+1):
    result = work_table[work_table['lifetime'] >= lifetime]['client_id'].nunique()
    count_id[lifetime] = result


rol_ret_table = pd.DataFrame.from_dict((count_id), orient='index').reset_index()
rol_ret_table.columns = ['lifetime', 'count_user']

rol_ret_table['rol_ret'] = round(rol_ret_table['count_user']/rol_ret_table['count_user'][0], 2)
rol_ret_table = rol_ret_table.rename(columns={'count_user': 'players'})




import plotly.express as px

ret_fig=px.line(
    rol_ret_table,
    x='lifetime',
    y='rol_ret',
    title='Rolling retention',
    labels={'lifetime':'День жизни','rol_ret':'Rolling retention'}
)
ret_fig.update_yaxes(dict(tickformat=".0%"))
return rol_ret_table
#return ret_fig
```

Comment: Вы можете вернуть кортеж и распаковать его: `def test(): ... return val1, val2; val1, val2 = test();`

Comment: Так тоже пробовал. Но так как у меня installs, logins глобальные переменные и объявляются в коде ранее, то при таком вызове функции Python начинает ругаться на то что у меня не объявлены installs и logins

Answer (score 0):

А если значения загнать в массив и вывести массив данных. А потом выдирать данные из массива.